# iPad jailbreak affect original application development?

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak

I am iOS developer.Now, I develop iPad an iPhone apps for my company. I have an iPad and now I have decided to buy my own Mac ;). I would like to develop applications to then upload to the AppStore.
Also I am interesed to jailbreak my device but before that I would like to know if this affect to the original development. If I could have problems to test original apps with orginal provisioning in my jailbroken iPad.

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a jailbroken iPad 1 running iOS 5.0.1 and I haven't had any difficulty provisioning it and testing my apps on it.

Comment: and, what sw u recomend to do the JB? absinthe??

Comment: @javiazo  I used redsnow.  I don't have any experience with absinthe.  You may wish to check out these [tutorials](http://www.iclarified.com/entries/index.php?caid=2&scid=30&seid=16) and pick a method that you are comfortable with.  I also recommend scanning through the comments for a particular method to see what sort of experiences others have had.

Comment: one more thing: iClarified has a [Jailbreak Wizard](http://www.iclarified.com/jailbreak/) that you can use to determine the available jailbreaking options for your particular  iDevice, Model, iOS version, etc.

Comment: ok, understood xD, thank u very much, iPad jailbroken without problems, thanks ;)

Comment: @javiazo  Damn, that was quick!  And thank you for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not affect your testing ability.